# Laravel pluck an array from nested relationship

Tags: laravel

I need to get only the `roomnumber` arrays returned from the following query:

```
$roomnumbers = Room::with(['floorroomcount' => function($query){
                $query->with('roomnumber')->get();
        }])->where('roomtype_id', $roomtype_id)->get();
```

Tried:
The follow pluck is returning `floorroomcount`

```
$roomnumbers->pluck('floorroomcount');
```

but i need `roomnumber` array, how can i get?

Comment: Did you try `$roomnumbers->pluck('floorroomcount.roomnumber');`?

Comment: yes, it give `[null,null,null]`

Comment: But if you `dd($roomnumbers);`, the `roomnumber` data does exist?

Comment: yes it exist, `room` and inside it has `floorroomcount` and inside it has `roomnumber`

Answer (score 30, accepted):

This gives you all `roomnumber` results in one collection:

```php
$roomnumbers->pluck('floorroomcount')->collapse()->pluck('roomnumber')->collapse();
```

Comment: yup super. it gives `roomnumber` array

Comment: i was searhing for long time to coimbine arrays, and `collapse` did it in nice way

Comment: There has to be a prettier solution, currently I have code like this:
`Group::with('service_groups.services')->get()->each->service_groups->each->services->pluck('service_groups')->collapse()->pluck('services')->collapse()->pluck('name');`

I know it's just a bit much, but it's basically a many to many to many relationship, so what can you do...

Comment: Update: I found a fix and posted it as an answer :)

Comment: `collapse()` is the answer, that just saved my whole life to handle nested relationship. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You may shorten @Jonas Staudenmeir's answer like so:

```
$roomnumbers->pluck('floorroomcount.*.roomnumber.*')->collapse();
```

`pluck('*')` is essentially the same as `collapse()` in this particular context.

Comment: Is the trailing `.*` necessary?

Comment: @Jonas Staudenmeir I honestly don't know, but actually it probably shouldn't be there at all... Given the `collapse()`, that is.

Answer (score 1):

This is working, but with many loop and echoing directly, if anything can be simplified please let me know :

```
   $roomnumbers = Room::with(['floorroomcount.roomnumber'])->where('roomtype_id', $roomtype_id)->get();

    $floorroomcounts =  $roomnumbers->pluck('floorroomcount');

    $records =  $floorroomcounts->map(function($floorroomcount, $value){

                    return $floorroomcount->pluck('roomnumber')->flatten();

                })->values()->all();        

    foreach($records as $record){

        foreach($record as $row){
            echo '<option value='.$row->id.'>'.$row->roomnumber.'</option>';
        }

    }

    //return response()->json($roomnumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
$roomnumbers = Room::with(['floorroomcount' => function($query){
    $query->with('roomnumber')->get();
}])
->where('roomtype_id', $roomtype_id)
->get();

$records = $roomnumbers->map(function($element, $value){
    return $element->map(function($e, $v){
        return $e->roomnumber;
    });
})->values()->all();
```

`map()` is a Laravel collection method so you need to import the collection facade on the top of the controller like: `use Illuminate\Support\Collection;`

Comment: changed `return $element->roomnumber;` its not working returning `[null,null,null]`

Comment: just ```dd($element)``` and ```dd($value)``` inside map() function, what are you getting?

Comment: `dd($element)` gives while `room` object. and `dd($value)` gives `0`

Comment: Try my updated answer. You will might get the nested array of room numbers, you need to flatten it. See https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-flatten

Answer (score 0):

In Laravel 5.1 and + you can use `flatten()` on collection.

> method [flattens](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/collections#method-flatten) a multi-dimensional collection into a single dimension:

```
$roomnumbers->flatten()->pluck('floorroomcount');
```