# Getting Only specific values from a PHP associative array

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

I get a Laravel collection from a Eloquent query and I converted into an array using `toArray()` method. The sample output is mentioned below.

```php
Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [details] => routes [level] => beginner [created_at] => 2022-11-16T11:09:48.000000Z [updated_at] => 2022-11-09T11:09:48.000000Z [pivot] => Array ( [user_id] => 1 [milestone_id] => 1 ) ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [details] => router 2 [level] => beginner [created_at] => 2022-11-09T11:09:48.000000Z [updated_at] => 2022-11-18T11:09:48.000000Z [pivot] => Array ( [user_id] => 1 [milestone_id] => 2 ) ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [details] => route [level] => route 3 [created_at] => 2022-11-15T09:05:46.000000Z [updated_at] => 2022-11-17T09:05:46.000000Z [pivot] => Array ( [user_id] => 1 [milestone_id] => 3 ) ) ) 1
```

I only need the values of `milestone_id`s from `pivot` index. As an example like this `[1,2,3]`

I tried different PHP methods and notations to access these values but couldn't succeed.

Comment: What did you try and what specifically went wrong?

Comment: Related: [Laravel pluck an array from nested relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50249341/2943403) and [Laravel pluck fields from relations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40635146/2943403) and [How to get only nested data in Laravel collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69844985/2943403)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [pluck](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/collections#method-pluck)

```
$milestoneIds = $collection->pluck('pivot.milestone_id')->toArray();
```

Comment: This worked! Thank you! I used `implode()` method to get only the values.

Answer (score 0):

You could `foreach` or `array_map` through the array

```
$milestone_ids = array_map(function($data){
    return $data['pivot']['milestone_id'];
}, $pivot);
```

The other way would be to use a loop to go through each data set in the array and get the value you are looking for and drop it in another array.

https://www.mycompiler.io/view/7jWliNt2Vo0